# Using EXCEPT keyword in BigQuery with non-table values

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I want to compare table metadata (columns, data_types) with some hardcoded values.
How to realize in BigQuery the following usual SQL logic?

```
select column_name, data_type 
from `bigquery-public-data.austin_311.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMN_FIELD_PATHS`
except
(select 'complaint_type' as column_name, 'STRING' as data_type
union all select 'complaint_description', 'STRING')s
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT column_name, data_type 
FROM `bigquery-public-data.austin_311.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMN_FIELD_PATHS`
WHERE NOT (column_name, data_type) IN (
    ('complaint_type', 'STRING'), 
    ('complaint_description', 'STRING')
  )
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, Mikhail!

Comment: Сould you please advise how to perform the opposite query (union hardcoded values and then compare with table) ?

Comment: it is hard to answer within the comments - please post new question with all details and I will answer it.